# How do I get notified about a client disconnecting from a Spring SseEmitter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a Spring Boot application with an endpoint, that returns a `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter`.

Multiple clients connect to my backend and their `SseEmitters` get stored (in memory), so that they can send each other messages via another endpoint, which the server then forwards to all connected emitters.

My problem is, that the `SseEmitter` class only has `onCompletion`, `onError` and `onTimeout` events. Neither of them gets called when a client simply disconnects.

Is there a way to see when a connection gets disconnected? Or maybe a way to get the underlying socket and listen for it to close or something?