# SseEmitter does not throw IOException on client disconnect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-ann-async.html#mvc-ann-async-disconnects):

> The Servlet API does not provide any notification when a remote client goes away. Therefore, while streaming to the response, whether through [SseEmitter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-ann-async.html#mvc-ann-async-sse) or [reactive types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-ann-async.html#mvc-ann-async-reactive-types), it is important to send data periodically, since the write fails if the client has disconnected.

This is supposed to manifest as an `IOException` when calling the `SseEmitter::send()` method, however I am using Spring + Embedded Tomcat 9.0.64 and this exception is never thrown and therefore cleaning up unused emitters is not possible.

I am using the following code:

```
try {
    emitter.send(SseEmitter.event()
            .id(event.getId().toString())
            .name("update")
            .data(data)
    );
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.info("Dead emitter detected. Removing...");
    deadEmitters.add(emitter);
}
```

In this case the exception is never triggered. Am I doing something wrong?

I am expecting an exception to be thrown as per the documentation.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64783914/how-do-i-get-notified-about-a-client-disconnecting-from-a-spring-sseemitter) has asked something similar, but in this case it seems the documented solution simply does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this for posterity as there seems to be little explicitly written about the topic:

SSE doesn't provide a mechanism for the client to tell the server about the fact that it has disconnected and TCP doesn't include this information either. In order to be correct, the server must send responses so long as can (i.e. until a server timeout).

The correct solution is to perform a 'heartbeat' call on the client every X seconds to tell the server "Yes I'm still here" and then sweep up connections that have failed to report back in time.

Websockets do not need this as they provide a mechanism to provide heartbeats (PING/PONG) by default.